# The content database has a schema version which is not supported this version

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, restore

We have a SharePointServer2013 installed with SQL Server 2014. But we need to restore site collection into another SharePoint2013 farm installed with SQL Server 2012. Any possible way to restore to Higher Version of Database.
[image]

Comment: Check this article **[This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm SharePoint 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/this-content-database-has-a-schema-version-which-is-not-supported-in-this-farm/)**

Answer (score 1):

At first you run [Test-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607941.aspx) to see if you're missing fetures or site definitions. If you do, you need to install the solutions and site definitions that are missing.

```
Test-SPContentDatabase -name "wss_content" -webapplication http://sp76:2222 -ServerInstance "SP76"
```

When you have a successful run of Test-SPContentDatabase, you run [Upgrade-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607813.aspx), which will migrate the database schema of your content database to the 2013 farm schema.

```
Upgrade-SPContentDatabase wss_content
```

When your database is upgraded, mount it using the cmdlet [Mount-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607581.aspx).

Comment: I don't think Upgrade-SPDatabase will run on a non-attached DB (I remember having to attach them first the last time I migrated to a newly-built farm with a later build version before I could run the upgrade).  I'd also check the ULS logs to get a detailed error message of the failed Mount-SPContentDatabase command.  It usually provides a much more detailed error message.

Comment: Hi Benny, here in my case, database is in SQL Server 2014, need to restore in SQL Server 2012, which means Downgrade Database

Answer (score 0):

I have also received this error when attempting to mount a content database from one SharePoint 2013 farm to another. The issue in my case was the patch level difference between the source and destination farms.

If the destination farm is on a previous patch level, update the destination farm to the source farm patch level.

If the destination farm is on a newer patch level, update the source farm to the destination farm patch level before backing up the database to restore to the destination farm.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, Ornery.. Here in my case Database is in SQL Server 2014 and need to be restored to SQL Server 2012. I found that we can downgrade SQL Database, but I could not find that SharePoint Content Database can downgrade

Comment: Hey Srinu, can you confirm that the two SharePoint 2013 farms are at the same patch level? I'm suggesting that perhaps the version of SQL is not the issue, but perhaps the issue is in fact due to differing patch levels between the source and destination SharePoint 2013 farms.

Comment: yes Orney, SharePoint 2013 Patch levels are the same 
PS C:\Users\sp_farm> (Get-spfarm).buildversion
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
15     0      4569   1000

Answer (score 0):

Refer this good article on that:

[This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/12/05/this-content-database-has-a-schema-version-which-is-not-supported-in-this-farm/).